# Searching for a file in all Volume Shadow Copies

Tags: vss

A file was lost sometime in the last months. Part of the filename is known. The exact directory is not known, only that it must be somewhere below C:\MyFolder. Neither is the creation or deletion date. I could open every saved VSS copy of C:\MyFolder and search for the file, but there are many saved VSS copies, and that would be a quite time consuming task.

Is there a way I can do a `dir c:\myfolder\*myfile*.* /s` over all saved VSS copies at once?